# Wireshark do not display multicast package going from my computer

Tags: wireshark, multicast

I have my computer communicating with another device using the multicast address 239.0.0.1:4123. The IP address of my computer is 192.168.1.250 and the IP address of the other device is 192.168.5.168. The netmask is 255.255.0.0.

Now, when I look in wireshark, I see packet coming from 192.168.5.168 with the destination set to 239.0.0.1 (and port 4123). Therefore, I can see that my device is sending packet to my computer. However, I cannot see my computer sending any packet on 239.0.0.1 (in fact, no packet seem to be sent from my computer). I can see on the device that packet sent from my computer are received, therefore the issue seemed to be in wireshark.

For some reason, I am not able to see packet sent on the address 239.0.0.1 from my computer. I am also not able to see the join. Is this ringing bells to anyone ?

Thank you

Comment: Your routing table isn't routing multicasts to the router for 192.168. You can overcome that via binding, or by setting the multicast interface explicitly on the socket. Or possibly your socket is bound incorrectly.

Comment: From my understanding, the issue was that wireshark was using winPcap. I updated wireshark to a more recent version and it ask me to install nPcap instead. After that, everything was working fine